# Apple developer dashboard - App IDs section is missing

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, apple-developer-account

I want to add push notifications to my app, the client share to me access to his apple developer account, but there is no "App IDs" section https://take.ms/AsVcO
It looks like different https://take.ms/GRO5x
is this a problem with access level?

Answer (score 0):

In the second screen shot, you have clicked Certificates (in the column on the left). You're looking in the wrong place. Click Identifiers.

Comment: There still might be a problem with your access level, but you won't find out until you look in the Identifiers section.